# How does IIS know which DLLs to use for a Visual Studio project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

On my development machine, I have IIS pointed to the root project folder of my ASP.NET web api project, and this works.  So my question is, how does IIS know that the dll's are in the "bin" folder, and not in the root?  In addition to this, i have switched my CPU target, so now there are lots of dll's in the bin folder, so how does IIS know which dll's to use in the "bin" folder, and is there a way to configure which dll's it uses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not IIS but the ASP.NET module (either `aspnet_isapi.dll` or `webengine4.dll`) who loads your assemblies. More information can be found in

https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-asp-net-on-iis-8f49e2bcefcd

The actual loader

- First checks `Global.asax` (hardcoded name) to know which `HttpApplication` derived class to load (as ASP.NET pipeline for incoming requests).
- Then scans the assemblies in `bin` (`bin` is hardcoded) to locate the actual `HttpApplication` derived class. Its `protected void Application_Start()` method is called to perform all registration (routing and so on).

So IIS has no idea what ASP.NET is. It is ASP.NET that hooks to IIS via the standard interfaces.

Comment: Are you sure it scans for a compatible class, instead of looking in `global.asax` for the `Inherits` tag?

Comment: Do you know what is the compiled result of `global.asax`? Check a sample project and you will see it would also be derived from `HttpApplication`.

Comment: Yep, understood, so you have at least two classes that inherit from HttpApplication, which precludes the notion of scanning as the sole means of identifying the right class. I would suggest that the framework will look at the global.asax file first.

Comment: Revised the answer accordingly. It seems to check Global.asax first, and then locate the class in the target assembly.